# How can i make the href links work on a safari extension popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, safari-extension

I'm creating a Safari Extension that has a pop over with a couple of links. However the links don't open when click on, Does anybody know how to get this working?

Here's a Sample of my popup file

```
<body>
<div id="container" class="clr">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.apple.com/" class="app-btn">
        <div class="btn-icon-container">
            <div class="btn-border"></div>
            <img src="apple.png" alt="Apple">
        </div>
        <div class="btn-text-container" style="width:46px;left:14px;">
            <span class="ban-text">Apple</span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://nytimes.com/" class="app-btn">
        <div class="btn-icon-container">
            <div class="btn-border"></div>
            <img src="nytimes.png" alt="NyTimes">
        </div>
        <div class="btn-text-container" style="width:78px;left:-2px;">
            <span class="ban-text">NyTimes</span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://stackoverflow.com/" class="app-btn">
        <div class="btn-icon-container">
            <div class="btn-border"></div>
            <img src="stackoverflow.png" alt="StackOverflow">
        </div>
        <div class="btn-text-container" style="width:80px;left:-3px;">
            <span class="ban-text">StackOverflow</span>
        </div></div></body>
```